# Identify users who touch files to prevent moving to slow storage

Tags: linux, touch

I have two storage systems, Primary (GPFS, fast, 400TB) and Secondary (Isilon/Netapp, slow, 2.5PB). A rule exists to move from Primary to Secondary all files that have not been accessed in the last N days. Some users run a "touch" on their files via cron so that they remain in Primary - they do so even if they don't need to access those files. What is a way to identify those users?

Example: I have a file /home/user1/file1 which I don't want to be moved off primary storage ever. I run a weekly cron job that runs `touch /home/user1/file1` which updates the atime.

There is a system-wide script that runs weekly, scans the primary filesystem and moves all files with an atime older than N days to secondary storage. Since /home/user1/file1 has a current atime, it will never get moved.

Hope this is clear. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should add more information about the environment and how you've implemented these "rules" to your question.

Comment: be grateful that they are using 'touch' instead of sha1sum. in other words, this is not a good time to start an arms race.

Comment: Currently, a script checks the atime of files and moves them to secondary storage if they have not been accessed in the last N days. Since it is easy to update the atime on a file, users run their own script to touch their files to keep them current and avoid getting them moved to secondary. The environment is Centos. I need to find a way to identify the users doing so.